# Swiping between View Controllers in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

In Swift, I currently have the following code in my first view controller, yet when I swipe nothing happens? What is wrong with my code? Do I have to implement something else? Thanks alot SO users, appreciate it.

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    }

     override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }

    var myViewControllers = Array(count: 4, repeatedValue:UIViewController())

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        let pvc = segue.destinationViewController as UIPageViewController

        pvc.dataSource = self

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);

        var vc0 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstViewController") as UIViewController
        var vc1 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as UIViewController
        var vc2 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThirdViewController") as UIViewController
        var vc3 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FourthViewController") as UIViewController

        self.myViewControllers = [vc0, vc1, vc2, vc3]

        pvc.setViewControllers([myViewControllers[1]], direction:.Forward, animated:false, completion:nil)

        println("Loaded")
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var currentIndex =  find(self.myViewControllers, viewController)!+1
        if currentIndex >= self.myViewControllers.count {
            return nil
        }
        return self.myViewControllers[currentIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var currentIndex =  find(self.myViewControllers, viewController)!-1
        if currentIndex < 0 {
            return nil
        }
        return self.myViewControllers[currentIndex]
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, your code is working perfectly for me. I made a trivial test (never having used a UIPageViewController before) with a button to segue from the initial VC to the Page VC, and two disconnected VCs in the storyboard to be constructed programatically with your code (I pasted it direct from above) and given to the Page VC. Each of the 3 visible pages was identified with a label. And they all work fine.

Does your UIPageViewController get instantiated? Do your two delegate routines above get called?

I suspect that you have not set up your storyboard appropriately. Here is mine:

[image: Storyboard screengrab]

When iOS runs your app, it transfers control to the initial VC. That's the one that you're writing your code in, called `ViewController` in the above source. That is not a `UIPageViewController`; it's an ordinary `UIViewController`, it says so here:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
```

The `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` bit just says it also provides the routines that tell a `UIPageViewController` what to display. When you do a segue out of `ViewController`, the `prepareForSegue` code runs then, and programs the destination of the segue, which is expected to be a `UIPageViewController`, with the other 4 VCs. To make the segue work, I dragged a `UIButton` to the first `ViewController` in storyboard, and dragged a `UIPageViewController` onto the right. Then control-drag from the button to the UIPageViewController. You should get a popup asking what kind of segue you want. I chose modal. When you run the app, you should see the button. When you press the button, you should see VC1, and swiping left or right will show the others.

Comment: When you swipe left to right, does it work across VC's? All I have done is paste the code in my first VC, although there should be more I have to do. I have a UIPageViewController, but does it specifically have to be identified and linked somehow? All I did was paste the code and expected it to swipe left to right. Also, I don't want to use buttons/labels to segue, just swiping.

Comment: Oh my its working! Thanks, although, when it comes to my table views where the user must swipe for options on the row, when i swipe it the VC changes not the tableview row options. Can i override this?

Comment: Also, how do applications like Snapchat make it so the whole paging effect doesn't show but it changes VC when you swipe, so it's more clean, or is that a completely different thing? Am i able to implement a page control? If so, how can i do this?

Comment: Congratulations! I think you should ask new questions if you want more.